# Exceeding the specs----Optiplex 740 Desktop: Can the motherboard (0YP806 / YP806) handle MORE than 8 GB?

Tags: memory, motherboard, memory-limit, dell-optiplex

Dell Optiplex 740 / Windows 7 Ultimate x64

All the specifications show that this MB (Dell 0YP806) can handle a max of 8 GB.

However, in the past I've had luck with exceeding memory in motherboards....the addressing units seem to be a bit or so wider than expected.  I've done this many times.

**Is this the case with the 740, or am I stuck at 8GB?**  I'm currently using all 4 slots with 2GB each.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you're stuck at 8 GB. I've never actually tried to go over what the manufacture's stated max amount of RAM. So I really don't have any idea if that means it won't work at all if you have more than 8 GB. However, if you did go over the stated maximum, it could cause a lot of instability with your RAM which would cause other problems like BSODs, etc. I'd definitely recommend staying at 8 GB, but if you're willing to push the risk, go for it. Just don't get frustrated if things start acting crazy.

Comment: Instability?  Not likely.  It'll be evident if it's good or bad quickly.  If it passes the POST, and then also passes the subsequent memtest86+ rigor I put them through, then the memory almost certainly will be just fine. A few things might happen though, and not of it will be a surprise flakiness that occurs over time: 1. The system will fail outright with a crazy mobo beep diag. 2. The system might only recognize the first 2GB of each slot. or 3. The system might recognize only the first 2 4GB sticks and ignore the second bank entirely. At least this has been my experience many times before.